# jQuery conditions pass through

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made my own form validation just for 2 inputs, one is for Phone number and another one for Email address. and also I have 2 forms in 1 page.

my code is

```
var email, phone;

if (email address validation passed) {
    email = true;
} else {
    email = false;
}

if (phone number validation passed) {
    phone = true;
} else {
    phone = false;
}

if (!(phone && email)) {
    return false
} else {
    return true
}
```

as I have two forms on the same page, I'd like to have another snippet for the 2nd form like,

```
var email2, phone2;

if (email address validation passed) {
    email2 = true;
} else {
    email2 = false;
}

if (phone number validation passed) {
    phone2 = true;
} else {
    phone2 = false;
}

if (!(phone2 && email2)) {
    return false
} else {
    return true
}
```

the issue I found is that, for getting the form submitted I need to have `email, phone, email2, phone2;` all equal to true. however, I need to submit in condition if `email, phone are true` or `phone2, email2 are true`
Just need someone to check if this is a right logical way to solve my problem?

```
if (!(phone2 && email2)) {
    return false
} else if(!(phone  && email )) {
    return false
} else return true;
```

Comment: `return ((email && phone) || (email2 && phone2));`

Comment: Why not show the forms - perhaps we can just have ONE validation

Comment: Would there ever be `email3` and `phone3`? :)

Comment: Also, you're missing a `{}` in the very last else clause where.

Comment: @olo - NOT specific to this question but based on review of your questions, http://jsfiddle.net/E2V4B/1/

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Thank you for the sample :-) if I have different buttons, one is "myclicker2" this method will not be working?

Comment: @olo - true, the idea would be to set a class on the elements, including the button - or you could change the selector to include ALL the id's of all the buttons - but having classes on all the "similar" elements would be key here - review how the fiddle has two forms and `class=` on elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> however, I need to submit in condition if email, phone are true or phone2, email2 are true

The way you said it there is the easiest way to code it:

```
if ((email && phone) || (email2 && phone2)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

And if you are just going to return true or false based on whether a condition is true or false, you can do it in one line like this:

```
return (email && phone) || (email2 && phone2);
```

Comment: Yes, forgot `||` Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can check it like

```
if((phone2 && email2) || (phone && email))
    return true;
else
    return false;
```